# Would the CLR optimize and inline this GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, optimization, clr, inline, jit

Let's say we have a value type like this, where the fields are `readonly` and initialized during construction:

```
public struct SomeValue
{
    private readonly Int32 field1;
    private readonly Int32 field2;

    ...
}
```

Also, let's say we have a helper class that lets us implement `GetHashCode()` for composite types in a reusable manner:

```
public struct SomeValue
{
    ...

    public override Int32 GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashHelpers.GetHashCode(this.field1, this.field2);
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler must realize that the field values aren't ever going to change after the type is constructed, since they are `readonly`. Is it therefore likely that the call to `HashHelpers.GetHashCode()` will somehow be inlined when `SomeValue.GetHashCode()` is JIT-ed?

Comment: You're not talking about inlining, but short-circuiting the GetHashCode implementation.

Comment: @Simon: What do you mean by *short-circuiting* in this context? Please elaborate.

Comment: You want the SomeValue.GetHashCode to directly return a pre-computed (computed during the last call) value. (Creating a quicker path, short-circuiting, through SomeValue.GetHashCode.) Inlining means that the code of the HashHelpers.GetHashCode will (assuming some criterias are met) be inserted into your SomeValue.GetHashCode to speed up execution (by avoid the method call which requires stack modifications, execution jumps, etc). I am just saying that what you're describing isn't inlining.

Comment: It sounds like you want (or at least ask about) the CLR to have some kind of ability to determine if a method call is deterministic (same input => same output) and to short-circuit those calls by replacing them with the cached value from a previous execution.

Comment: @Simon: Ah, I see what you mean. I guess that taken to its extreme, that *could've* been what I meant, but I actually *did* mean inlining, as in doing the exact same calculation sequence without the function call overhead.

Comment: @Johann:  But inlining has nothing to do with the readonly part.  Memoization/short-circuiting does though.  Inlining would work just as well regardless of whether the values could change.

Comment: @recursive: Ok, that's what my question is about. I wanted to know if inlining would be affected by readonly. If I had known the answer, then I wouldn't have to ask. I might have formulated the question too fuzzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post the code for your HashHelper method, but since it should be small and fast, yes, it is quite likely that it will get inlined.

And, yes, the JIT optimizer is quite capable of evaluating expressions at compile time and replace the code with a simple constant value.  But that is not going to happen when you use a *readonly* member.  Because the value it has is determined by the constructor.  The optimizer does not consider the code in other methods to guess if the field has a known value.  It must be able to detect the value when it compiles GetHashCode.

You can get this if you use a const to initialize the readonly field.  And use that same const in the GetHashCode implementation.  That's pretty ugly.  Given the very limited benefit you'll get from this micro-optimization, this is probably not something you should consider.  The possible win is no more than a nano-second or so.  But most likely zero because the optimizer would replace a xor with a mov.

Comment: The code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416 with changes to make it generic for several parameters.

Comment: Well, I'm sure your code doesn't look exactly like that.  Details matter when the JIT optimizer makes inlining decisions.  Nevertheless, it doesn't change my answer.

Comment: Well, I'm sure I explicitly noted that it wasn't exactly like that with the *"with changes to make it generic for several parameters"* : http://pastebin.com/Fx6HCnPL

Answer (score 3):

There are some [well-known](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx) rules for inlining (.NET 4 might have added more). In your case if `HashHelpers.GetHashCode` is simple enough, it will be inlined. I don't think that those readonly fields are of any meaning in that context.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the fact that your fields are declared as `readonly` has no bearing on whether or not the jitter decides to inline the method.

Here's an article discussing some of the heuristics used by the .NET 3.5sp1 jitter. This may have changed in .NET 4, and could change again in future versions.

- [To Inline or not to Inline: That is the question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the call to HashHelpers.GetHashCode() won't be inlined, it will just count as a normal call to that method in the CIL. I may be wrong, but I'm fairly sure that I'm not.

Comment: I think that he is speaking of inlining at JIT time, not compile time. As far as i know the c++.net compiler is optimising it's CIL output but the C# compiler is just spiting a translation of the C# code as CIL without doing any optimisation.

Comment: Understood. Sorry if I misunderstood the question there.